# Using jQuery, how do I add a class to elements that have an href that has part of the path of the active element's href?

Tags: jquery, class

I would like the "Quick", "Brown", and "Fox" links to have the "dropdown" class, but not for the "Foo" or "Bar" links. How can I achieve this using jQuery?

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/foo"> Foo </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/foo/bar"> Bar </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/quick"> Quick </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/quick/brown"> Brown </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/quick/brown/fox" class="is-active"> Fox </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/3t9yy4ou/

```js
var activeHref = $('.is-active').attr('href');
$('a[href]').each(function(){
  if( activeHref.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) >= 0){
    $(this).addClass('dropdown');
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/foo"> Foo </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/foo/bar"> Bar </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/quick"> Quick </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/quick/brown"> Brown </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/quick/brown/fox" class="is-active"> Fox </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've used `jQuery` `.each` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the element attribute as href with .attr('href,'link') which will let you edit and also you can get the current active by adding the ul reference to a var or directly and after search all the $('.is-active') inside and there you'll have the active value or element name. I hope this has helped you
If i missunderstood something, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Get the `href` of the active element

```
const activeHref = $('.is-active').attr('href')
```

Then find all elements with an `href`, filter it by the above value and add the class

```
$('[href]').filter(function() {
  return activeHref.indexOf(this.getAttribute('href')) !== -1
}).addClass('whatever')
```

```js
const activeHref = $('.is-active').attr('href')
$('[href]').filter(function() {
  return activeHref.indexOf(this.getAttribute('href')) !== -1
}).addClass('whatever')
```

```css
.is-active { font-weight: bold; }
.whatever { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/foo"> Foo </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/foo/bar"> Bar </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/quick"> Quick </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/quick/brown"> Brown </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/quick/brown/fox" class="is-active"> Fox </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```